# Why does my Python thread with subprocess not work as expected?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have the following subtle problem:
The Python code starts two threads, each creating a subprocess call to an exexutable (in fact written in C). The first executable is passed the argument 10000, meaning a delay of 10s before its exits. Similar for the second executable, but with a delay of 20s.

I observe, that worker1 and worker 2 do their printouts at the same time, namely after 20s, the longer of both delays. Why is `wait()` for worker1 somehow "blocked" by the longer delay of the other? Whatever I pass as arguments, both print outputs are right after the longer of both times.

Note: This is a boiled down example for demonstration purposes and not the code I'm working on. Anyway, it is not related to print output, in my original code instead of print I do something more complicated.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time


def worker1():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["../testapp1.exe", "10000"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    ret = proc.wait()
    print("result worker1:%s ret:%d" % (outs, ret))
    print("done")


def worker2():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["../testapp2.exe", "20000"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    ret = proc.wait()
    print("result worker2:%s ret:%d" % (outs, ret))
    print("done")


job_thread1 = threading.Thread(target = worker1)
job_thread1.start()

job_thread2 = threading.Thread(target = worker2)
job_thread2.start()

job_thread1.join()
print ("after join1")
job_thread2.join()
print ("after join2")
# time.sleep(20000) original
```

The executable:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int count;
  //printf ("This program was called with \"%s\".\n",argv[0]);

  int sleep = 0;

  if (argc > 1)
  {
      for (count = 1; count < argc; count++)
      {
          if (count == 1)
          {
              sleep = atoi(argv[1]);
          }
          printf("\nargv[%d] = %s\n", count, argv[count]);
      }
  }
  else
  {
      printf("The command had no other arguments.\n");
  }

  int fin = sleep;
  for (int i=0; i<fin; i++)
  {
      for (int i2=0; i2<100; i2++);
  }
  //Sleep(sleep);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: when I remove "communicate" it works for some reason. But in this case I cannot get the output of the process...

```
def worker1():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["../testapp1.exe", "10000"], shell=False, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    # outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    ret = proc.wait()
    print("result worker1:%s ret:%d" % (outs, ret))
    print("done")
```

EDIT2: Using only wait(), I found, that it is blocking at the marked label, where the output from the pipe is read...

```
def worker1():
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["../testapp.exe", "100000000"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        ret = proc.wait()
        xread = proc.stdout.read() ### !!!! BLOCKS
        print("xread:",xread)  
        sys.stdout.write("done-1")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except ComError as e:
        print("got exception")
        raise e
```

Comment: Why do you do a `time.sleep` in the end? I would try doing a join on both jobs instead...

Comment: Are you sure the executables are correct ?

Comment: Because my real world application is a handler and never ends. But even when I replace sleep() with join() I get the same behaviour.

Comment: The executables are correct. I testet both (simultaneously) with the same parameters from two shells. When started by this Python script, testapp1 disappers from Windows Task manager after 10s, as expected.

Comment: I tested your program with my own executable. Worked just fine. Printed texts with 10 secs difference. Please check your executables.@michael

Comment: The executabe seems to be OK. I checked it together with a colleguage. I'm under Windows 7. You? Anyway: strange...

Comment: I am on Windows 10 machine. @michael

Comment: @vkgade : and your Python version? Mine is 3.4.2

Comment: @michael I am using Cygwin with Python 2.7.13.

Comment: @vkgade: I tested it under Python 3,4,2 and also 3.6.1. Always the same. I give up...

Comment: @michael Like others I've tested it locally and it works as expected. A few things to note:

* In your pasted example you are calling 2 *different* executables . Are both being created from the same source code ? (as you question implies)

* In your pasted example of the C code, the sleep is commented out. Is that how your current test executable is being complied ?

* Remember that "print" would be buffered. So it is possible, for your OS you don't get to see the print statements although thread1 has already printed it. You may want to do a sys.stderr.write() instead.

Comment: @ lonetwin: STRANGE...yes they are in fact the same executable, but copied. So out of one executable I made two other executables with different names.Does this matter????? Originally I had it with the Sleep() but I changed it to nested loops to eliminate problems with this sleep function.

Comment: @ lonetwin: changing print to sys.stderr.write doesnt help either

Comment: @michael what about using `sys.stdout.write("string")` following by `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: @ lonetwin: Flush doesnt't help. I did it. See my comment in the main: Using only wait(), I found, that it is blocking at the marked label, where the output from the pipe is read...could there a problem with the pipe/IO ? BTW: the C program now flushes stdio also - fflush(stdio)

Comment: @michael Are you sure it is that print that is blocking and not the line above it?  If it is the print, then try using `sys.stdout.write` instead in place of `print("xread:",xread)` (followed by a flush again)

Comment: sorry, of course the line above is blocking.

Comment: @michael Your executable is very uncertain on execution timeline. A nested for-loop does not ensure anything. Even though worker1 has less iterations than worker2, still there is a chance worker2 is done first. Most cases there will be a difference of a second or two. You need to use `sleep` to see the 10 seconds difference.

Comment: sleep() doesnt't change anything...See my new posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706866/why-is-my-output-from-a-subprocess-delayed-when-it-is-generated-from-a-python-t