# Why is my output from a subprocess delayed, when it is generated from a Python thread?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, subprocess, python-multithreading

This an extension to my posting from yesterday, which is still unsolved: [Why does my Python thread with subprocess not work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688923/why-does-my-python-thread-with-subprocess-not-work-as-expected)

In the meantime I found some interesting details, so I decided to create a new posting. To bring it to the point: There are some issues, when a subprocess is generated out of a thread.

Platform: Windows 7 Enterprise, Python 3.6.1

In the following code I want to run a C-executable and get its output to `stdout` into a string. For test purposes the executable accepts two parameters: a delay and a filename (not used here). The program writes `Sleep now` to `stdout`, sleeps for the given number of milliseconds and finally writes `after sleep` and `END`.

This is the C-source of the executable:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sleep = 0;
    FILE * outfile = NULL;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        sleep = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    }

    printf("Sleep now...\n");

    Sleep(sleep);

    if (outfile) fprintf(outfile, "output-1");
    printf("after sleep\n");
    printf("END\n");

    if (outfile) fclose(outfile);
    fclose(stdout);
    exit (0);
}
```

This is the Python code:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import os
import sys


def worker_nok(*args):

    exe, delay, filename = args
    proc = subprocess.Popen([exe, delay, filename], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    print("%s:" % (filename,), out)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def worker(*args):
    exe, delay, filename = args
    flag = True
    proc = subprocess.Popen([exe, delay, filename], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while flag is True:
        str = proc.stdout.readline()
        if str == b"":
            print("%s: got EOF" % (filename,))
            flag = False
        else:
            print("%s:" % (filename,), str)
    print ("%s: END" % (filename,))
    sys.stdout.flush()


all = []    

"""
# 4 seconds
job_thread1 = threading.Thread(target = worker, args=(["../testapp.exe", "4000", "w4sec.txt"]))
job_thread1.start()
all.append(job_thread1)

# 8 seconds
job_thread2 = threading.Thread(target = worker, args=(["../testapp.exe", "8000", "w8sec.txt"]))
job_thread2.start()
all.append(job_thread1)
"""

# 4 seconds
job_thread3 = threading.Thread(target = worker_nok, args=(["../testapp.exe", "4000", "w4sec.nok"]))
job_thread3.start()
all.append(job_thread3)

# 8 seconds
job_thread3 = threading.Thread(target = worker_nok, args=(["../testapp.exe", "8000", "w8sec.nok"]))
job_thread3.start()
all.append(job_thread3)



for t in all:
    t.join()
```

The jobs have delays of 4, 8, and 1 seconds, respectively.

`worker_nok` calls `proc.communicate()` - it was my original approach, which is not working: When running the two jobs, I get the following output:

```
w4sec.nok: b'Sleep now...\r\nafter sleep\r\nEND\r\n'
w8sec.nok: b'Sleep now...\r\nafter sleep\r\nEND\r\n'
```

The whole bunch is received after 8 seconds. Instead I would expect

```
... 4 sec ...
w4sec.nok: b'Sleep now...\r\nafter sleep\r\nEND\r\n'

... 4 sec ...
w8sec.nok: b'Sleep now...\r\nafter sleep\r\nEND\r\n'
```

Although the process with 4 seconds is definitely finished, its output is available only after the second job has also finished.

This was the state from my last posting.

To find out whats wrong, I tried to replace `communicate()` by direct reading of stdout, which is implemented in the `worker` function. The EOF condition is identified when read returns an empty string. When calling it, I get:

```
... 4 seconds ...

w4sec.txt: b'Sleep now...\r\n'
w4sec.txt: b'after sleep\r\n'
w4sec.txt: b'END\r\n'

... 4 seconds ...

w8sec.txt: b'Sleep now...\r\n'
w8sec.txt: b'after sleep\r\n'
w8sec.txt: b'END\r\n'
w8sec.txt: got EOF
w8sec.txt: END
w4sec.txt: got EOF
w4sec.txt: END
```

However I would expect:

```
w4sec.txt: b'Sleep now...\r\n'
w8sec.txt: b'Sleep now...\r\n'

... 4 seconds ...

w4sec.txt: b'after sleep\r\n'
w4sec.txt: b'END\r\n'
w4sec.txt: got EOF
w4sec.txt: END

... 4 seconds ...   

w8sec.txt: b'after sleep\r\n'
w8sec.txt: b'END\r\n'
w8sec.txt: got EOF
w8sec.txt: END
```

The big **Questions** are:

(**1**) Why at all is there a delay before I get `sleep now` ? The executable makes this output available without delay. Is the stdout only available after the process has terminated?

(**2**) More important: Why is the EOF for the 4sec available only after the 8sec call has finished?

I hope this input makes clear, why the original version showed the observed behavior: The `stdout` is in the EOF-condition much too late and leaves the call to communicate() blocking!

I appreciate any inputs, since I'm working on that already for more than 12 hours...

Comment: Sounds like you have a [buffering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973870/why-does-python-keep-buffering-stdout-even-when-flushing-and-using-u). Does it make a difference if you run Python in unbuffered mode, `python -u`?

Comment: I didn't even know that: but unfortunately it gives the same result.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try. It _could_ also be buffering on the C side. I haven't written much C in recent years, but I'm pretty sure that the stdio library does buffering when you write to pipes, but there should be functions that allow you to control the kind & amount of buffering. Hopefully someone more familiar with this stuff will be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: I remember some years ago having trouble on MSWindows with a GUI application to run a console application (in a sub-process) and print stdout/stderr to scrollable text views. We didn't get output of stdout/stderr (via pipes) before console application had finished. Portable solutions like glibs `gspawn()` didn't solve the problem at that time. Finally, we developed a native solution with a separate thread for `exec()` and duplicated pipes which worked finally. (I would tell you in more detail. Just had a look into the code but I struggle to understand quickly what we did that time.)